Ubuntu studio installation
Ubuntu studio 24.10. newby
Hi . I'm new to Linux. I'd like to try the latest Ubuntu studio, installed on USB drive with persistence.
I'm trying to install to my surface pro 5.
USB drives, 32gb and 128gb(new)
I've tried both drives. Flashed the iso with rudus, booted, got to the manual partitioning page of the install, but can't get any further. I can't check the boxes for the drives..
I managed to get gparted installed, by copying the iso to the drives and install from the terminal commands. The drives are already unmounted .
The drives are on a USB hub, as the surface pro only has the one usb3 port.
If anyone has some ideas I can try that would be great thanks in advance
